# Flask handle_exception doesn't work with test_request_context

Tags: python, flask

I noticed that `app.handle_exception` doesn't seem to be called when the exception occurs with an `app.test_request_context`:

```
from flask import *

app = Flask(__name__)
app.handle_exception = lambda e: 'exception!'

@app.route('/foo')
def foo():
    x = 1 / 0
    return 'ok'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #app.run(port=81) # handle_exception works here
    with app.test_request_context('/foo'):
        print app.dispatch_request() # but not here
```

Is this the expected behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily override this behaviour and force handling exceptions with same handler.

```
def run_test(path=None,check_func=None,*args,**kwargs):
    with app.test_request_context(path,*args,**kwargs):
        try:
            data=app.dispatch_request() 
            if check_func is not None:
                 check_func()
            else:
                print data
        except Exception as e:
            print app.handle_exception(e)

run_test('/')
run_test('/other')

def current_test(data):
     assert 'has some content' in data
run_test('/should_be_checked',check_func=current_test)
```

And another word.

Your approach does not work because you just do not use that part of Flask, which actually catches Exception. You are calling context directly.

Quote from documentation:

> If you look into how the Flask WSGI application internally works, you will find a piece of code that looks very much like this:

```
def wsgi_app(self, environ):
    with self.request_context(environ):
        try:
            response = self.full_dispatch_request()
        except Exception, e:
            response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
        return response(environ, start_response)
```

---

But!
Following would be the correct way to do it, since all Flask methods on every level will be called in appropriate way:

```
with app.test_request_context():
    with app.test_client() as client:
        resp = client.get('/')
        #and if you need content of response: print resp.data
```

### ---

Comment: Thanks. Of course I can do it that way, but as `handle_exception` works the "normal" way (and is actually the mechanism I'm interested in, for a blog post I'm currently writing), it would be more elegant in my context to be able to use it with a `test_request_context` as well (just for test/demonstration purposes). So that's why I'm asking.

Comment: Updated answer. Now it actually includes answer :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the good explanation and `test_client`, which I wasn't aware of.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you're after: according to the [docs for dispatch_request](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Flask.dispatch_request):

> Does the request dispatching. Matches the URL and returns the return
>   value of the view or error handler. This does not have to be a
>   response object. In order to convert the return value to a proper
>   response object, call make_response().
>
> Changed in version 0.7: This no longer does the exception handling,
>   this code was moved to the new full_dispatch_request().

So, perhaps replace...

```
with app.test_request_context('/foo'):
    print app.dispatch_request() # but not here
```

...with...

```
with app.test_request_context('/foo'):
    print app.full_dispatch_request() # Hopefully this works now :)
```

Comment: This looks interesting and relevant, but I'm not sure how to use it in my context though.

Comment: Almost! I'm pretty sure it would work in another context, but in mine, I actually need to do something *between* `app.before_request` and `app.dispatch_request`, so I guess I cannot escape using `app.test_request_context`, wich allows me to use `app.preprocess_request` (at the inevitable cost of `handle_exception` I fear).